# how to convert ucs4 to ucs2 using C++ and ucs2 to ucs4?

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding

Is there any C++ method support this conversion?
By now i just fill character '0' to convert ucs2 to ucs4, is it safe?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct for UCS2, but that's most likely not what you have. Nowadays, you're more likely to encounter UTF-16. Unlike UCS-2, UTF-16 encodes Unicode characters as either one or two 16-bit units. This is necessary because Unicode has more than 65536 characters in its current version.

The more complex conversions usually can be done by your OS, and there are several (non-standard) libraries that offer the same functionality, e.g. ICU.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that. Hope it will help:

```
String^ StringFromUCS4(const char32_t* element, int length)
{
    StringBuilder^ result = gcnew StringBuilder(length);
    const char32_t* pUCS4 = element;

    int characterCount = 0;
    while (*pUCS4 != 0)
    {
        wchar_t cUTF16;
        if (*pUCS4 < 0x10000)
        {
            cUTF16 = (wchar_t)*pUCS4;
        }
        else 
        {
            unsigned int t = *pUCS4 - 0x10000;
            unsigned int h = (((t << 12) >> 22) + 0xD800);
            unsigned int l = (((t << 22) >> 22) + 0xDC00);
            cUTF16 = (wchar_t)((h << 16) | (l & 0x0000FFFF));
        }

        result->Append((wchar_t)*pUCS4);

        characterCount++;
        if (characterCount >= length)
        {
            break;
        }

        pUCS4++;
    }

    return result->ToString();
}
```